# Double-checking integration of $\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z^4+1}$ on rectangle with vertices $\pm 1$ and $i\pm 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute
>
> $$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^4 + 1}$$
>
> where $\gamma$ is the rectangle with vertices $\pm 1$ and $i \pm 1$ oriented clockwise.

Using the principle of homotopy, I reasoned (either correctly or incorrectly) that this could be equivalent to the parametrization

$$\gamma_1 = (-2t + 1), \quad 0 < t < 1$$

$$\gamma_2 = e^{it}, \quad \pi > t > 0$$

This gives me

$$\begin{align} \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^4 + 1} &= \int_0^{1} \frac{-2dt}{(-2t + 1)^4 + 1} + \int_\pi^{0} \frac{i e^{it} dt}{(e^{it})^4 + 1} \\[8pt]
&=\int_{1}^{-1} \frac{du}{u^4 + 1} + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{u^4 + 1} \\[8pt]
&= 0\end{align}$$

Did I do everything correctly?

Comment: as @David said the path you choose is not homotopic to the original one, because the space where the homotopy is defined is the domain of the integrand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by residues, if you have studied that topic.  I'll leave out the justifications, but basically:
$$\eqalign{\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z^4+1}
  &=-2\pi i\sum_{z=e^{i\pi/4},\,e^{3i\pi/4}}{\rm Res}(f,z)\cr
  &=-2\pi i\sum_{z=e^{i\pi/4},\,e^{3i\pi/4}}\frac1{4z^3}\cr
  &=-\frac{\pi i}2\bigl(e^{-3\pi i/4}+e^{-i\pi/4}\bigr)\cr
  &=\frac{\pi i}2\Bigl(2i\sin\frac\pi4\Bigr)\cr
  &=-\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\ .\cr}$$

In using homotopy you must make sure that you don't cross over any singularities when you change the path.  In this case - even worse! - you have landed right on top of the singularities, which are $e^{it}$ for $t=\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4$.  Also, when evaluating the integrals you have substituted and then substituted back again.  So in effect you are assuming that the integral of $f(u)$ from $1$ to $-1$ is independent of path, which it isn't.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{4z^3}$?

Comment: If $p,q$ are analytic and $q(a)=0$ and $q'(a)\ne0$, the residue of $p(z)/q(z)$ at $a$ is $p(a)/q'(a)$.